# Create an Int64Index of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have just started learning code in Python and I am trying to create an Int64Index of a column in my data frame and print the index. I am trying the following codes, but none of them is working:

First:

```
age = index(data = df.columns(age)).astype(Int64, copy=True)
```

Alternate:

```
age = df.Int64Index(name = age)
```

For reference see the picture, I am taking another example where I used Groupby() year and calculated the mean and got the resulted data frame. I want to add Int64Index to the resulted data frame.

[image: This image shows the resulted dataframe created from groupby()]

Comment: Can you create a simple dataframe then show the expected outputs?

Comment: df.index = df['Year'].astype(Int64, copy=True)

Comment: `g.reset_index()` ?